# Arabic font is not displayed correctly in TextView

Tags: android, string, fonts, textview, arabic

trying to add Arabic text to my project, but two problems arise:

- the glyph for the letters ل and ا is not matched (لا)
- the vowels aren't spaced correctly

It looks like:
[image]

This is not a problem with the font, because in other programs it works as it should? textDirection="anyRtl" doesn't help

TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_ayah_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/uthman_taha_naskh_regular"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="اللَّهُ لا إِلٰهَ إِلّا هُوَ الحَيُّ القَيّومُ" />
```

Comment: When you say `in other programs it works as it should` what do u mean by that ?
is it working in Some other place in your app . i always find RTL support in android problematic ..

Comment: @ADM ahah I mean MS Word and the site where I downloaded the font. It doesn't work everywhere in my app. Actually RTL support in android has gotten much better in recent years, but it's still a problem, right

Comment: Your problem is not with Direction something that can be fixed easily, your problem is with text drawing which is internal stuff .. try with Some other arabic fonts just for testibg see if you see any difference

Comment: @ADM I've tried several Arabic fonts, there are some that work fine and some that have the same problem. But this font is the most common, I see it in many applications so it should work fine.
It looks like the glyph reader reads ltr instead of rtl and because of that it doesn't find the right glyph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the letterSpacing for TextView in the themes. Removed it and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
//Add this code in java file
textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL).
//And in textview
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not work